# Reset Android Widget when process exits

Tags: android, android-widget

My Android app has a widget.

While my app process is running, the widget remains in a state corresponding with the state of the app. When the process is gone, I need to reset the state of the widget.

When the Android OS cleans up your application, there is no notification sent to the code before the process exits.

Any ideas on how I can reset the state of the widget?
Also, any way to get notified that your process is about to be GC'd?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't tie widget or other UI state to process state, since the user is not directly aware of processes being started and stopped, and the act of a process being killed in the background is generally divorced from what they think they are doing.

Comment: Umm, why? If I have an app that plays music, the Widget must show the current state. If the app is GC'd or closed using the Task Manager, the Widget should reset. How do I do that latter step?